# PHP cuts data after 1000 vars

Tags: php, variables, post

I have a form that contains about 4000 variables (all variables are arrays, like var1[], var2[], etc.) and is submitted using POST.

The problem is that after submitting form, PHP leaves only 1000 variables (so the final result is 10 arrays containing 100 elements each) and cuts everything rest.

I already changed max_input_vars and suhosin.post.max_vars from 1000 to 10000, but no effect. PHP info is available at http://lipskas.com/phpinfo.php

What else should I change?

Comment: You _did_ restart the http server after changing the php configuration?

Comment: You _really_ should think about whether that strategy is good design. Thousands of parameters for a single request is just insane. Even if you solve your problem, you have no control over things like proxies inbetween and the like. Instead of dealing with the symptom you should fix the cause!

Comment: Yes, I restarted Apache. As for strategy, the person wants to load data from his CSV file and perform all the calculations without using any vars from database, so the only way to do it was output CSV variables as hidden fields in form

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree: there _certainly_ are other options. If this is an interactive thing you could use ajax to transfer single or smaller groups of parameters or limit the transfer to only those parameters that actually got changed and if this is _not_ an interactive thing then the obvious solution is to transfer all parameters as a single one in encoded form, maybe json or even csv.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a solution to the problem above

Comment: Again, try to increase the post_max_size in php.ini and restart apache.

Comment: post_max_size was increased from 8 MB to 64 MB, didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase the max_input_vars value in php.ini:

```
max_input_vars = 1000
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote in my original post